# How to use liferay tabs

Tags: liferay-6

I need to develop a simple plain login page with out any images and all.Once the user is logged in it should display like the image in the below link.

```
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+Tabs+in+Liferay+Portlets
```

Sample Tab1,Sample Tab2,Sample Tab3 i can achieve using liferay tabs.But how can i get that HomeA1,Reports tabs.And firstly i am not even getting the login page also.I am getting mad with this liferay.But this is the task for me to complete.Please any help will be appreciated.Sorry for my poor English.

thank You

Answer (score 0):

Since you've managed to show the "Sample Tab1,Sample Tab2,Sample Tab3", go and replace

```
String tabNames = "Sample Tab 1,Sample Tab 2,Sample Tab 3";
```

with

```
String tabNames = "HomeA1,Reports tabs,Whatever-you-like";
```

The link you gave us, covers this part. I really think you could give it a more careful reading. And if you keep having problems, you should provide some code or error logs